# Make option in form disabled When already requested

Tags: django, django-models, django-filter, disable

I am building an web app that allows users to request items.
The user will select the item, the location, the start date and end date of the borrowing in a form.
I have the following model which I created the form from:

```
class Request(models.Model):
    shootkit = models.ForeignKey(Shootkit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    request_start_date = models.DateField('Start Date')
    request_end_date = models.DateField('End Date')
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have [5 Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpATJ.png) in the database.

And here's the model:

```
class Shootkit(models.Model):
    shootkit = models.CharField('Shootkit', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

And the def in views:

```
def request_form(request):
    submitted = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = requestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            stock = form.save(commit=False)
            stock.username = request.user
            stock.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/request_form?submitted=True')
    else:
        form = requestForm(initial = {'username': request.user})
        if 'submitted' in request.GET:
            submitted = True

    return render(request, 'request_form.html', {'form':form, 'submitted':submitted,})
```

The issue here is that I want to grey out (disable?) the items options which have been already requested.
so I know that I can filter the date greater or equal than today in objects in the Request table so it means that the item still unavailable. But I am not sure how to block/disable the item.

Can anyone help please?

(EDIT)
Apologies if my question is not clear.
Please see requestForm:

```
class requestForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Request
        fields ='shootkit', 'location', 'request_start_date', 'request_end_date',
        widgets = {
            'request_start_date':DateInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'request_end_date':DateInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'shootkit': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-select'}),
            #'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'location': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-select'})
        }
```

and here is a pic of the [request_form.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPqyl.png)
my intention is that if any of those shootkits ( for example shootkit #2 and shootkit #4 have been requested and the end date of the borrowing is next week for example. Then the shootkits should appear as disabled in the form [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hi0qb.png)

I hope that makes more sense.
Thank you.

Comment: I think this requires further clarification. I'm not sure what do you mean by options (shootkit instances?) Can you add the requestForm class definition and the request_form.html template? This way we'll have a clearer understanding of what you are trying to do.

Comment: And yes, sorry, by options I mean the Shootkit table instances.